# PostgreSql: cannot use aggregate function in UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I have an Oracle query that I ported to PostgreSql:

```
UPDATE "SPD_PG"."TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29" 
SET "SECT_ORDER" = MAX("SECTIONS"."SECT_ORDER")+1 FROM "SPD_PG"."SECTIONS"
INNER JOIN "SPD_PG"."META_SECTIONS" ON ("SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID"="META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID")
WHERE ("META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ORDER"="TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."META_SECT_ORDER"-1)
AND ("SECTIONS"."DOC_ID"="TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."DOC_ID")
AND ("TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."META_SECT_ORDER">0)
```

This give me: `ERROR: cannot use aggregate function in UPDATE`, seems PostgreSql doesn't support `MAX` in Update statements.

However if I rewrite the query as follows:

```
UPDATE "SPD_PG"."TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29" 
SET "SECT_ORDER" = "MAX_VALUE" FROM (
  SELECT MAX("SECTIONS"."SECT_ORDER")+1 AS "MAX_VALUE" FROM "SPD_PG"."SECTIONS"
  INNER JOIN "SPD_PG"."META_SECTIONS" ON ("SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID"="META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID")
  WHERE ("META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ORDER"="TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."META_SECT_ORDER"-1)
  AND ("SECTIONS"."DOC_ID"="TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."DOC_ID")
  AND ("TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."META_SECT_ORDER">0)
) "TBL_ALIAS"
```

it says `ERROR: subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level`.

So I can't figure out how to write this query.

Comment: I think your second version should work on postgresql 9.3.

Comment: @Eelke Sorry I forgot to specify I'm on 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE "SPD_PG"."TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29" 
   SET "SECT_ORDER" = (SELECT MAX("SECTIONS"."SECT_ORDER")+1 
                         FROM "SPD_PG"."SECTIONS"
                        INNER JOIN "SPD_PG"."META_SECTIONS" ON ("SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID"="META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID")
                        WHERE ("META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ORDER"="TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."META_SECT_ORDER"-1)
                          AND ("SECTIONS"."DOC_ID"="TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."DOC_ID")
                          AND ("TT_SPLDR_11A2F324_29"."META_SECT_ORDER">0)
                      )
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I imagine that If I've had more than 1 value to set, I would have had to repeat the subquery for each value...?

Comment: Yes, You need to repeat this subquery for each value. But it is a bad idea to store aggregate values in the table. Have you heard about normalization? If I were you I would use a view.

Comment: This is a batch process for loading a configuration in the database. I need to do some adjustments to already present data, and I need the `MAX("SECT_ORDER")` for a particular `DOC_ID` (think of sheets in Excel).

Comment: BTW, I found that SQLServer (2008 R2) has the same issue with aggregate functions in update statements